# MVC 3 versus MVC Turbine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, turbine

I have implemented my own inversion of control methodology in MVC 2.  I was thinking of reviewing MVC Turbine and possibly switch to that.  However, I noticed today that MVC 3 Preview 1 has been released and has new inversion of control support built in.  I know it will be a while before it is released, but wanted to see if anyone knows if the new inversion of control support will basically make MVC Turbine unnecessary.

What do you think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although MVC3 features overlap those that MVC Turbine currently provides (filter support, controller injection, etc.), I do not foresee MVC Turbine going away because of that :)

My intent is to provide the same features that MVC Turbine currently offers with the new MVC3 bits since the new additions to the framework provide ease some of the friction that MVC Turbine had to overcome in MVC1 and MVC2.

As the MVC3 bits solidifies, so will final features of MVC Turbine V3 that deal with DI/IoC support. Essentially MVC Turbine will evolve to provide composition support to ASP.NET MVC applications and lean on the DI features of MVC3 for the 'under the covers' plumbing.

If you have any questions with regards to best currently utilize MVC Turbine with your MVC1/2 applications don't hesitate to contact me or ping the [Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/mvcturbine) for information.

Comment: Thanks Javier!  Can't wait to see what you do with it.  Hopefully, I will be able to play around with Turbine soon to see if it will replace what I have already done.  I may take you up on that offer of help. :)

Comment: Sure thing, Brian! Anything to help out a fellow ASP.NET developer :)

Answer (score 1):

MVC Turbine is not about just providing IoC support. It is more about composition, components discovery and auto-registration capabilities (thus more overlapping with MEF than MVC3 DI features :).